# best approch to implement Azure Key Vault with Vuejs and Azure Pipeline

Tags: php, laravel, azure, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

In order to protect secrets ( database password, ... ), my application ( php laravel / vue js ) would use Azure Key Vault.

However, I'm so confused about how I can use the azure key vault :

If I use some PHP library, the application will be slower ( Always need to interact with key vault to connect to the database for example )

or I get the secret from the key vault in Azure pipeline + I insert the value in the environment file (.env file)

Someone Can help me, please?

Comment: Hi, I'm experimenting with this myself, I don't suppose you ever found a sufficient solution to this? Just curious if you could knowledge share?

Answer (score 1):

Either option should work fine. You could mitigate the issue with connecting live to Key Vault by caching the values in memory instead of retrieving them from key vault every time you make a connection. Assuming you retrieve the values as part of startup, that will slow down, but the rest of the application will run at the same speed. This is the method that I would recommend- it maximizes the security benefits of using Key Vault.

If you would like to integrate Key Vault into your pipeline you can use a [Key Vault task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops) to retrieve the values. The built-in file transformation tasks in Pipelines currently only handle XML and JSON files, but there are 3rd party solutions like the [Replace Tokens task](https://github.com/qetza/vsts-replacetokens-task) that may work for you in updating the .env files.

Comment: using php memcached is enough to store the value as part of startup ?

Comment: My php knowledge is limited, so I can't tell you if it's the best option, but a in-memory key-value store like that should work.